# Access to the specified resource has been forbidden in simple Spring webservice Demo

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-ws

I have created simple spring security demo with REST webservice.
    I have spent lot of hours on It.Need strong pointers regarding simple working spring security for rest webservice with latest versions.
    My Controller is

```
@Controller
public class RestContoller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/countryJSONProduce", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<CountryDetail> getCountryJSON() {

        CountryDetail countryDetail = new CountryDetail("Values");
        ResponseEntity<CountryDetail> rentity = new ResponseEntity<CountryDetail>(countryDetail, HttpStatus.OK);

        return rentity;
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/countryJSONConsume", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String consumeJSON(@RequestBody CountryDetail countryDetail) {
    System.out.println("Country Detail Example");
        return "home";
    }
}
web.xml is 

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/springrest-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


my pom.xml is
<properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- for Jsp use -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring mvc and Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring mvc and Core -->
        <!-- JSON Response Spring Framework 4.1, the minimum jackson version should 
            be 2.1 -->


        <!-- Compatiable Spring Framework 4.1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Authentication Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Authentication End -->

    </dependencies>

When I Run the code sometimes it shows popup in my Eclipse Mars INTENAL
browser for user and password.when i put my credentials it will goes to
localhost:8080/SpringMavenRest2/ welcome page ok.when I hit the
url localhost:8080/SpringMavenRest2/hello/countryJSONProduce
which is calling my first service.. it is showing the Error :Access to
the specified resource has been forbidden.403
Even I put user name and
password as basic auth.Now I am testing this second url  FROM CHROME
POSTMAN CLIENT.
I am using this configuration Java 1.8 ,Tomcat 8.0
spring.version4.1.0.RELEASE ,springsecurity.version 4.0.2.RELEASE.
and maven 3.3
Its
working well without authentication.Could you give any best referenced demo
for spring security with basic authentication.  I have refered this also
 http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/
```

Comment: my spring-security.xml  is <security:http auto-config='true'>
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
       access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
      <security:http-basic />
     </security:http>
    
    
     <security:authentication-manager>
      <security:authentication-provider>
       <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="sandip" password="12345"
         authorities="ROLE_USER" />
       </security:user-service>
      </security:authentication-provider>
     </security:authentication-manager>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/hello/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER'') "/>
and / or 
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY','ROLE_USER')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks  I tried first option.its working could  you provide any  link for basic security reading